# ASP.NET Core - System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: Произошла ошибка безопасности

Tags: c#, httpclient, asp.net-core-mvc

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь из WEB-приложения отправить запрос на внешний API ВКонтакте и получить ответ. Ранее всё получалось, ошибок не возникало. После обновления через Visual Studio Installer стало вылетать.
`` System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: Произошла ошибка безопасности
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.d__105.MoveNext() ``

Ошибка происходит конкретно при отправке запроса

```
Json = await Client.GetStringAsync($"access_token?client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri={Domain}/{AuthRoute}&code=" + value);
```

ASP.NET Core 2.0, Visual Studio 2017
Предполагаю, что проблема с System.Net.Http.dll

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была с моим VPN соединением и решилась сменой VPN сервера.